# Live Search with Golang on HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, go

I'd like to run a [search](https://github.com/renstrom/fuzzysearch) and display its results as soon as the text of an `<input>` changes.

How could the program get the value from the `<input>` when it changes?

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search">
<section id="results"></section>
```

Comment: You have no choice but javascript on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post you value to Golang with ajax.

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
txt=$("input").val();
$.post("url",{suggest:txt},function(result){
     $("#results").html(result);
     });
   });
```